# Why is Tkinter not displaying Button?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.x

```
import Tkinter as ass
root = ass.Tk()
frame = ass.Frame(root)
button1 = ass.Button(frame, command=button1(), text='Kushagra', width=50, height=40)
button1.pack(side=ass.LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

`button1()` is a function I made which i don't think is relevant. After I run this all I get is a blank window. How do I fix this?

Comment: @martineau: def button1():
                           global a
                           a += 1
                           return a

Comment: I was wrong about what it does being important, so have deleted my earlier comment—although my point about not calling it when creating the `Button` widget is still valid. @Deepak Raj's answer is why nothing is displayed (although he doesn't specify the `command` option at all).

Comment: @martineau Sorry if I'm annoying by asking questions repeatedly but what did I do wrong when calling button1()? Could you please correct me.

Comment: Generally speaking, when you want to specify a callback function while creating a tkinter widget, just use its name, without the `()` prefix — i.e. `command=button1` in this case. Note however there is another potential problem in this case, since when you assign the widget to `button1` it overwrites its original value and afterwards the name will no longer refer to the original function you defined. On the other hand, it may not matter if you never call the function the explicitly from that point on.

Comment: P.S. To avoid confusion and potential problems, I suggest you give the function a unique name…such as `button1_callback`.

Comment: @KushagraSharma My answer would help you.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't pack the frame widget after creating the frame. The below is the edited code

```
import tkinter as ass
root = ass.Tk()
frame = ass.Frame(root)
frame.pack()
button1 = ass.Button(frame, text="QUIT")
button1.pack(side=ass.LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to `pack` the frame if you want it to be displayed. This will let the button to be shown but the function `button1()` won't work as you want because it would be called when it is given to the `Button` as a `command`, As you have used parenthesis `()` after giving it to the button as a `command`. You just need to remove those parentheses.

Like this:

```
import tkinter as ass


def button1():
    return


root = ass.Tk()
frame = ass.Frame(root)
frame.pack()
button1 = ass.Button(frame, command=button1, text='Kushagra', width=50, height=40)
button1.pack(side=ass.LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

And if you need to pass arguments to any function then you should use `lambda` before giving it as a `command` to any `Button`.

Like this:

```
import tkinter as ass


def test(a):
    print(a)


root = ass.Tk()
frame = ass.Frame(root)
frame.pack()
button1 = ass.Button(frame, command=lambda: test(1), text='Kushagra', width=50, height=40)
button1.pack(side=ass.LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```